# Error When trying to connect Pentaho User console to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, odbc, pentaho, kettle

I try to create data source in Pentaho User Console where I want it to connect to SQL Server 2000 using ODBC access. When I test this connection, I got this error:

[image: error]

Why this error come out? Can someone tell me why & how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332/en-us

Comment: Thanks for that link. I still having same error. Don't know why. But thanks for that link.